# Cannot disable proxy caching

Tags: .net, caching, proxy, squid

I've got a C# web client application that uses RestSharp library to access a third party web service. In some environments it has to work via a proxy. I'm using WebProxy framework class to provide the proxy details and everything works just fine. Except one edge case.

The proxy (Squid in my case) is configured to require credentials.

If my code sends a request **with** WebProxy credentials and immediately after that (less than a minute) another (exactly the same in my case) request **without** credentials, I nevertheless receive a OK response instead of 407 (authentication required) error.

I've tried multiple suggestions found here and in other Internet resources:

- using CachePolicy with NoCacheNoStore
- defining "cache deny all" in Squid
- calling "DeleteUrlCacheEntry" of WinInet.dll
- providing random timestamp parameter to make request url unique
- adding cache control headers to the request

To no avail. I'm pretty sure that RestSharp is not to blame as I was able to trace the execution inside this library up to the point where it uses the underlying .Net APIs. RestSharp respects the both the proxy and the caching policy settings and passes them on to .Net classes.

I have not tried yet other proxies - just Squid.

I'd be glad to hear any ideas and/or suggestions in solving this problem.

Regards,